# X and Y are uncorrelated, but X becomes significant when X*A is included in model

Tags: r, multiple-regression, interaction

At the zero-order level, X is not correlated with Y. When I add X and A into a regression analysis to predict Y, only A is a significant predictor. A itself is correlated highly with Y at zero-order. However, when I add an interaction term into the analysis, A*X and X significantly predicts Y, and A no longer predicts. What does this mean? What kind of variable is X, and what kind of variable is Y?

```
# additive model
Call:lm(formula = Y ~ X + A, data = dat)
Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-30.247  -8.150  -1.416   8.692  24.263 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  67.3713     9.8646   6.830 2.04e-09 ***
X             0.4805     2.1935   0.219    0.827
A           -10.4961     1.8172  -5.776 1.69e-07 ***

# interaction model
Call:lm(formula = Y ~ X * A, data = dat)

Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-20.778  -8.834  -2.135   8.925  24.410 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)     -17.620     40.762  -0.432   0.6668  
X                30.294     14.057   2.155   0.0345 *
A                10.275      9.841   1.044   0.2999  
X:A              -7.297      3.400  -2.146   0.0352 *
```

Comment: This question isn't very clearly stated. Can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simulated data that shows a similar result (R code):

```
A <- -5:15
x <- A + rnorm(21)
y <- A^2 + rnorm(21)

summary(lm(y~x+A))
summary(lm(y~x*A))
```

In this case y is directly related to A, but in a non-linear relationship.  The x variable is also related to A, but does not contribute to the relationship with y so the 1st regression shows it not significant.

But the interaction between x and A works as an approximation to A^2 and therefore contributes to the fit of the non-linear relationship.

This is one possibility, there are others as well that can lead to a non-linear (interaction, or other) relatioship only showing up in some cases.  If you change the above code to have `A<- -10:10` then A is not significant in the 1st regression.